# Joomla Insert Content into product details

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I use VirtueMart. I need to add some content to product details page to specific DIV. I cant only change template. I need to do this by php because it will be Joomla plugin.

Comment: When you need specific Joomla support, here is a sensible place to post: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Look at the override system for customizing Joomla, it also applies to Virtuemart. You can add code or simple html to the product details page and place it in the templates HTML folder (where overrides go).

If you only wish to have this on some products, you can have that product details file named something other than default.php and then it will be available to select as the layout to use in the Virtuemart product edit screen.

Comment: Problem is how to do it automatically and how to support other themes. And what about compatibility with other plugins which use this view?

Comment: Ok, I didn't get that you were looking to use a Joomla plugin to do this on multiple Joomla sites. To use Joomla content plugins in Virtuemart you also need to toggle a switch in Joomla > Virtuemart > Configuration > Shop (tab), check the Enable Joomla Plugin checkbox.

With that in place, standard Joomla content plugins will work.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. But how can I insert content to some element and how to support more themes? Is there some way how to do that?